# Set-ClusteredScheduledTask change the 'action'

Tags: powershell, cluster-computing, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to modify the action of a clustered scheduled task - the file it needs to run has changed location, so I want to modify the schtasks job to reflect that.

I have been trying along the lines of the following, but it doesn't work...

```
$ClusterScheduledTaskName = "CLUS - CheckDB-Prod"
$ClusterScheduledTaskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell" -Argument "-file S:\DBA\BatchJobs\Live\Scripts\DBA\Backups\CheckDB_Servers-All_set_to_backup.ps1 -dbbackuptype ALL_DATABASES -backuplist S:\DBA\BatchJobs\Data\CheckDB-Prod.txt" 
set-ClusteredScheduledTask -TaskName $ClusterScheduledTaskName -Action "$ClusterScheduledTaskAction"
```

Error is:

```
Set-ClusteredScheduledTask : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Action', because PSTypeNames of the argument do not match the PSTypeName required by the parameter: 
Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#MSFT_TaskAction.
At line:1 char:72
+ set-ClusteredScheduledTask -TaskName $ClusterScheduledTaskName -Action "$Cluster ...
+                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ClusteredScheduledTask], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MismatchedPSTypeName,Set-ClusteredScheduledTask
```

Can anyone give me any pointers of where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have quotes round the "$ClusterScheduledTaskAction" Powershell is trying to expand the contents of the variable.  If you remove the quotes you should be OK.  Also don't forget to set a trigger!

```
set-ClusteredScheduledTask -TaskName $ClusterScheduledTaskName -Action $ClusterScheduledTaskAction
```

Comment: Thank you. Because I was editing the existing clustered task it kept the triggers from before.

Comment: Ahhh was thinking of normal scheduled task creation.